# Why can't my current user see their own inbox but can see another user's inbox?

Tags: django

So I am attempting to query and display messages between two users in an inbox. I am running into a problem where no messages are appearing for `request.user`. It's showing as empty when there are messages. However, when I go into an inbox for another user that my `request.user` has messaged while still logged in to `request.user`, I can see the messages from both parties there and displayed correctly.

So basically my current user cannot access their own messages. I know I need to pass `request.user` somehow into the template to query the messages correctly, but I'm not sure how.

**settings/Templates**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**messages.html**

```
{% for msg in messages %}


    {% if msg.receiver_id == user.id %}
        <li class="text-right list-group-item">{{ msg.message }}<br/>{{ msg.date }}<br/>{{ request.user.username }}</li>

    {% elif msg.sender_id == user.id %}
        <li class="text-left list-group-item">{{ msg.message }}<br/>{{ msg.date }}</li>
    {% endif %} 



    {% empty %}
{%endfor %}
```

**views.py/messages**

```
def messages(request, profile_id):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=request.user, receiver_id=profile_id,) 
            | Q(sender_id=profile_id, receiver_id=request.user,) ).\
        values('sender_id','receiver_id', 'message', 'date', ).\
        order_by('date',)


    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', {'messages': messages,})
```

**urls.py/messages**

```
path('messages/<int:profile_id>/', views.messages, name='messages')
```

**base.html/messages url href**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' user.id %}">Check Messages</a
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
from dating_project import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))

class InstantMessage(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'senderr',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

Comment: What about `{% if msg.receiver_id == request.user.id %}`?

Comment: Nope. The current user still can't see their own inbox. But it still works fine for seeing other user's inbox that the current user has messaged.

Comment: how do you represent messages in their own inbox? Does the `sender` and `receiver` both point to the user? Or is one `NULL`?

Comment: Well, the one's that the user is sending are displayed on the right and the ones that the user is receiving are displayed on the left ordered by date. What do you mean by NULL? And my views should be pulling messages from both users

Answer (score 0):

You `messages` method returns messages in the context but not `user` which is used in your template.

However, django can add the request to the context for you if you configure it to. By doing this you don't ever have to pass the logged in user in the context of your views because it's already there.

To do this, make sure [`django.template.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) is in your template context processors.

With this configured your template can do `{% if msg.receiver_id == request.user.id %}`

Comment: where would I find the context processor to put that line in? Or do I just stick it in the top of the template?

Comment: `settings.py` there you can add one it. If it is not listed there. By the way he linked docs see there.

Comment: things is, I just checked and it looks it was already there and still not working. I just added settings.py to my question.

Comment: @Rez it's one of the defaults so that doesn't surprise me. However when you say it's not working, what do you mean? If you put `{{ request }}` in a template, outside of any logic, and at a point you know content gets shown, what does it do? Likewise, then try `{{ request.user }}`.

Comment: request.user works. In fact, in the same template I posted above, I actually pass in request.user.username during the if statement, and the request.user's username shows up! But when I try putting request.user.id,  the way I was originally told, it doesn't work

Comment: Well in that case, does `{{ msg.receiver == request.user }}` show as `True`? If not, verify the user object against the message is the same as the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in `views.py/messages`. You're filtering for messages from user->profile or profile->user. But you're linking to a URL where profile and user is the same. So on that page you would only get messages where sender and receiver is the same.

```
def messages(request, profile_id):
    messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=request.user, receiver_id=profile_id,) 
            | Q(sender_id=profile_id, receiver_id=request.user,) ).\
        values('sender_id','receiver_id', 'message', 'date', ).\
        order_by('date',)


    return render(request, 'dating_app/messages.html', {'messages': messages,})
```

You should probably make a different view to display messages to/from current user with this query.

```
messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=request.user) | Q( receiver_id=request.user)).\
    values('sender_id','receiver_id', 'message', 'date', ).\
    order_by('date',)
```

EDIT: Suggestion using a Conversation model.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    @property
    def last_message_time(self):
        try:
            return self.instantmessage_set.order_by('-date').first().date
        except self.instantmessage_set.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join(self.members.all())


class InstantMessage(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'senderr',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, models.CASCADE)
    # Don't need this if it belongs to a conversation
    # receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

In a view you could access conversations using `{{ user.conversation_set.all }}`.

messages.html

```
{% for conversation in user.conversation_set.all %}
    <li class="text-right list-group-item">
        {% for member in conversation.members.all %}{% if member != user %}
            {{ member.username }}<br/>
        {% endif %}{% endfor %}
        {{ conversation.last_message_time }}
    </li>
{%endfor %}
```

Comment: I see now that I made a mistake, selecting with AND instead of OR. Edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: The problem with that is that it shows ALL messages rather than just the messages between a certain user and request.user

Comment: Yes, of course. If you only supply one user id, it can't possible decide which conversation to display. For that the user needs to choose conversation to show.

Comment: Which is why I did it the way I did it before.

Comment: Though for that method, that it still doesn't display messages in MY user's inbox. It displays them correctly in another user's inbox between my user, and it only shows the messages between those 2 users rather than all the user's that my user has messaged. But, as I added an href link underneath each profile, whenever I hit that link, it uses request.user's PK and takes it to request.user's inbox which is empty. The only way I have gotten my user to display messages is by querying messages with ONLY request.user BUT then it displays ALL messages rather than just the ones between specific usr

Comment: How would you suggest I do it then?

Comment: For the users inbox you would need a list of conversations, not the contents of the conversations. So, basically, you need to identify which users the current user has written to. The easiest way, and least heavy on the database I think, would be to create a Conversation model, which has a ManyToMany-field linking users, and then have each InstantMessage belong to a Conversation (ForeignKey). That way the list of Conversations for a user can be shown in the inbox.

Comment: Isn't that what I did with my 'InstantMessage' Model? It has two foreign keys making it a many to many field

Comment: Updated my answer to include what I'm suggesting. I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Great. I am confused about {{ user.conversation_set.all }}. You mean in my template I could access it? Or are you saying I should filter through conversation object instead of InsantMessage in views?

Comment: user.conversation_set.all() would be a queryset containing all of a users conversations. And yes, you can access that in you template, preferably using {% for conversation in user.conversation_set.all %}. Likewise for a Conversation object, which would have instantmessage_set.all(), being a queryset with all messages in that conversation.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I'm slightly confused, do you mean I should do two query's together? Do you mind editing my messages.html and posting it in your answer to clarify please?

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you said but I'm getting   `Exception Value: 
Cannot query "test1": Must be "Conversation" instance` when I try to access messages